# SVN: deleted repo subdirectory

Tags: linux, svn

While moving an SVN repo to another directory

```
svn mkdir <new-repo-dir>
svn move <subdir-1> <new-repo-dir>
...
svn move <subdir-n> <new-repo-dir>
mv .svn <new-repo-dir>
```

I then encountered a problem:

```
svn move mcsu/ MCSU_BLOCK2/
svn: E155035: Cannot handle status of '/run/media/jski/4c038dee-2d01-462e-beff-f68ac9b11efa/mcsu'
svn: E200042: Additional errors:
svn: E155010: The node '/run/media/jski/4c038dee-2d01-462e-beff-f68ac9b11efa/MCSU_BLOCK2/mcsu' was not found.
```

I then deleted mcsu/:

```
svn delete mcsu/ --force
```

and tried to recover it using:

```
svn update
```

and ended up with this:

```
Updated to revision 493.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
Searching tree conflict details for 'mcsu' in repository:
 done
Tree conflict on 'mcsu':
Changes destined for a directory arrived via the following revisions during backwards update from r493 to r493:
 (no revisions found)
A deleted directory was found in the working copy.
Select: (p) Postpone, (r) Mark as resolved,
        (u) Update any moved-away children, (h) Help,
        (q) Quit resolution: u
Tree conflict at 'mcsu' marked as resolved.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 0 remaining (and 1 already resolved)
```

All my efforts to recover mcsu/ result in nothing:

```
svn update
Updating '.':
Authentication realm: <https://path-to-repo:443> Subversion Repositories
Password for '<name>': ***************

At revision 493.
```

Suggestions on how I might get this subdirectory in the repo: mcsu ? It's on the server.

Comment: What are you really trying to do ? Moving the server part on the server or a working copy ? Because you're mixing _svn mv_ and _mv .svn_ directory in the same question. Moreover, please indicate what the form of_<new-repo-dir>_ and _<subdir-1>_. Are they real paths or URLs ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying:

```
svn revert --depth infinity mcsu
```

It appears to have worked. Not sure if this is the correct solution or even kosher?